# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 - Going out of bounds of array?

Tags: arrays, string, split, arduino, processing

I am sending 3 sensor values from Arduino to Processing and splitting the String into three elements in the array.
Sometimes when I run the program, I get the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 error and as far as I understand, it means that I am trying to access an element in the array that isn't there.
What am I doing wrong?

My code from Processing and Arduino is below:

PROCESSING:

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial port;
float background;
float r1;
int a;
int b;
int c;
PrintWriter output;
Databox Data1 = new Databox(20, 20);
Databox Data2 = new Databox(20, 190);
Databox Data3 = new Databox(20, 360);

void setup() {
  size (690, 530);
  port = new Serial(this, "COM3", 9600);
  output = createWriter(hour() + "." + minute() + "." + second() + ".txt");
}

void draw() {
  background(60, 40);
  Data1.drawDataboxHumi();
  Data2.drawDataboxTemp();
  Data3.drawDataboxMoist();

  if (port.available() > 0) {
    String inString = port.readStringUntil('\n');
    if (inString != null) {
      inString = trim(inString);
      String[] data = split(inString, '#');

      a = int(data[0]);
      b = int(data[1]);
      c = int(data[2]);

      output.println("Tidspunkt:" + " " + hour() + ":" + minute() + ":" + second() + " - " 
        + "Luftfugtighed:" + a +"%" + " "+ "Temperatur:" + b + " " + "Jordfugtighed:" + " " + c);
      output.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

ARDUINO:

```
#include <dht.h>

dht DHT;

#define DHT11_PIN 7

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(A0, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  int SensorValue = analogRead(A0); 
                                      

  int chk = DHT.read11(DHT11_PIN);

  Serial.print(DHT.humidity);
  Serial.print("#");
  Serial.print(DHT.temperature);
  Serial.print("#");
  Serial.print(SensorValue);
  Serial.println("#");
  delay(1500);
}
```

Comment: as @ocrdu mentions, data might be lost or Processing might open the port when Arduino is mid sending: there could a situation where a "packet" might be lost. Double check `if(data.length == 4)` as well before parsing `a,b,c`

Answer (score 0):

Try checking (by printing) what `port.readStringUntil('\n')` returns *exactly* every time, and in the same way check what is left of it after the `trim()`.

It could be `readStringUntil()` times out sometimes, and then returns `0` only, which is a string without any `#`s, which would `split` into a 1-element array. It could also be reading spurious data left in the buffer somehow, with the same effect.

The only way of finding out is checking the `inString` as said above.

You could prevent the run-time error by doing a check on the number of elements in `String[] data` before addressing the individual array elements, but that doesn't solve the onderlying problem. It could well be good enough for your purpose, though.

Remark:

You don't need to send the last (third) `#` from the Arduino; you only need two for splitting an Arduino `String` into three parts, and having three `#`s may lead to `split` yielding four parts. It will need a `\n` at the end, though.

Comment: It doesn't seem to time out. I have removed the 3rd "#", but no apparent improvement. When I remove it, the 3rd data-output "SensorValue" gets drawn as 0 in Processing when I run the program.

Comment: Print to screen what inString is after the line String inString = port.readStringUntil('\n'); exactly, and what inString is after the line inString = trim(inString); I suspect it will tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Also, try to see if it works properly if you reduce the `delay()` on the Arduino to 800; `readStringUntil()` has a default time-out of 1s. Also see edited answer.

Comment: Trim seemed to do nothing so I removed it. The code is based on an old excercise I did a couple of months back, so it was just a leftover from that. The issue also seems to have been fixed now. I inserted an if-statement

 if (data.length == 4){                                      
      a = int(data[0]);
      b = int(data[1]);
      c = int(data[2]);
      }
after String[] data = split(inString, '#'); and it seemed to have done the job. There are 4 elements in the array, but I can't get it to work with just 3 by removing the "#" in Arduino

Comment: That will prevent a run-time error from occuring, but doesn't solve the underlying problem.

Comment: The lowest amount of delay that seems to work in Arduino is 1200 milliseconds, otherwise the sensor reads -999

Comment: In that case, introduce the line: port.setTimeout(2000); or something like that in your Processing program. Not sure about the exact syntax.

Comment: I can't seem to find any reference to something called "timeout" with Serial, but perhaps port.buffer() works the same way?

Comment: You could try `port.bufferUntil()`, but that has a different syntax (needs a kind of callback function it will run when it finds a `\n`), and I don't know if it will solve the problem. You will have to take a closer look at what `inString` actually contains to see what the real problem could be.

Comment: When I print inString to the console i get the 3 values from the Arduino with the "#" inbetween like so: 51.00#24.00#1023#. I tried removing the last "#" but then the last value woudn't get displayed proberly when i ran the program

Comment: Did you still send a '\n' at the end when you removed the last #?

Comment: I think so. Is it correct that 'Serial.print("\n");' can be used by 'Serial.println(SensorValue);' instead of 'Serial.print'? It doesn't seem to make a difference whichever I use of the two.